# How to show a default image in an array with Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic project with the api from the [Movie Database](https://www.themoviedb.org). I have this array in an ng-repeat that shows me some images (cast pictures). But not all the images in the array have an actual picture.

[image]

Now I am trying to show a default image when the api does not provide an image. My question is how to do this with ng-if i suppose. In my controller I created a scope as followed:

```
  $scope.default_image = '../img/default_poster.png';
```

Part of my controller:

```
.controller('MovieDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $ionicLoading, MovieService) {

$ionicLoading.show({template: 'Loading ...'});

$scope.init = function(){

    MovieService.getCastCrewInfo($stateParams.id).then(function(data){
        $scope.casts = MovieService.castMovie;
        $scope.default_image = '../img/default_poster.png';     
    });

    $ionicLoading.hide();
}
```

})

Part of my HTML code:

```
<div class="content-cast">
            <!-- <h3>Cast</h3> -->
            <br>
            <hscroller>
                <ion-scroll direction="x" scrollbar-x="false" >
                    <hcard ng-repeat="cast in casts" >
                        <img ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154/{{cast.profile_path}} || default_image" >
                        <p class="cast-name">{{cast.name}}</p>
                    </hcard>
                </ion-scroll>
            </hscroller>
        </div>
```

Comment: Try with `ng-src="'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154/' + (cast.profile_path || default_image)"`

Comment: @sp00m, mm that does not seem to work. i get this -> https://gyazo.com/072adfaea1c879c571f03b70b1527a8a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a scope function or `ng-if`

```
$scope.getImage = function(item){
     return item.profile_path ? 'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154/' + item.profile_path :  $scope.default_image;
});
```

View

```
<img ng-src="{{getImage(cast)}}" >
```

For `ng-if`

```
 <img ng-if="cast.profile_path"  ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154/{{cast.profile_path}}">
 <img ng-if="!cast.profile_path" ng-src="{{default_image}}">
```

Comment: @charlieftl, thanks it worked with ng-if. much appreciated